# How can I fix my Realm problem for device

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I am trying to save my data in a real device and used realm manager something below. My problem is very interesting and I could not even have any idea what is wrong with saving data on my real device. **Every simulator works properly and I can save. But it doesn't work on a real device.**

Secondly, I could not find the realm DB file when I go to fileURL path it is empty. ( Document file )

```
(lldb) po Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL
```

Can someone help me please ? Full project is [here](https://github.com/annekariny/SimpleMarket), you can try it yourself if you wish. I would really appreciate it.

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

protocol RealmFactoryProtocol {
    func makeRealm() throws -> Realm
}

final class RealmFactory: RealmFactoryProtocol {
    private let fileManager: FileManagerProtocol
    private let currentSchemaVersion: UInt64 = 1
    private let appID = "com.karinyfreitas.SimpleMarket"

    init(fileManager: FileManagerProtocol = FileManager.default) {
        self.fileManager = fileManager
    }

    private var sharedRealmConfiguration: Realm.Configuration? {
        guard let containerURL = fileManager.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: appID) else {
            return nil
        }

        let configurationURL = containerURL.appendingPathComponent("db.realm", isDirectory: true)

        return Realm.Configuration(
            fileURL: configurationURL,
            schemaVersion: currentSchemaVersion,
            migrationBlock: { _, _ in },
            shouldCompactOnLaunch: { totalBytes, usedBytes in
                // Realm compacting approach from https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#compacting-realms
                let oneHundredMB = 100 * 1024 * 1024
                return (totalBytes > oneHundredMB) && (Double(usedBytes) / Double(totalBytes)) < 0.5
            }
        )
    }

    func makeRealm() throws -> Realm {
        guard let configuration = sharedRealmConfiguration else {
            throw RealmFactoryError.unableToMakeConfiguration
        }
        return try Realm(configuration: configuration)
    }
}

enum RealmFactoryError: Error {
    case unableToMakeConfiguration
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of that Realm code is correct, so I don't believe there's any problem with how you're creating new Realm objects.

However, I think you've got how `containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:)` works a little confused.

In this example, you're providing your app's bundle identifier to that API, but that's actually not what it expects. It wants a "group identifier" which specifies the name of a shared directory between an app and its extensions, that you define under "App Groups" in your app's Capabilities setting (More info on that is on [Apple's developer site](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_security_application-groups)).

Looking at the source code, it looks like you've already set up an app group called `group.simplemarket`.

So if you change

```
private let appID = "com.karinyfreitas.SimpleMarket"
```

to

```
private let appID = "group.simplemarket"
```

That *should* fix all of your problems here. Welcome to Stack Overflow!